# Cómo cortar una string en Python de derecha a izquierda, incluyendo toda la string?

Tags: python

Es posible incluir toda la string, recorriendola de la forma `string[number:number]` en python ?

Por que puedo hacer:

```
string = 'Hola';
```

`string[-3:-1]` pero no incluye todo, solo `'Hol'` , qué puedo hacer ?

Quiero hacerlo de derecha a izquierda solo para uso de conocimiento.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo más amplio que muestre a que te refieres con "recorrer"? No se si te refieres a un ciclo que muestre `'a', 'la', 'ola', 'Hola'` o es otra cosa. Para que el slicing retorne el último item/carácter debería ser `string[-3:]` o `string [-3:4]` (`string[-3:len(string)]`), lo cual mostraría `"ola"`.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es quedarte con las tres últimas letras del string, basta omitir el índice del final del _slice_. Es decir: `string[-3:]`. Si lo que quieres es la cadena completa (obtendrías una copia), basta omitir tanto el índice de inicio como e final, es decir, `string[:]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sigues usando la misma forma de "cortar" la lista. Recuerda que una cadena es una lista de caracteres.

Para hacerlo de derecha a izquierda usas esta forma:

```
texto[::-1]
```

Recuerda que para obtener los elementos de una lista usas [**inicio**:**fin**:**saltos**].

En este caso al no poner el numero de inicio y fin se toma el primer elemento y el ultimo elemento, entonces con el **salto** -1 le decimos que lo haga al revés.

Ejemplo:

```
texto = "hola"
print(texto[::-1])
```

Salida:

> aloh